# How can I get my time to stop so that my sprites can't attack each other after the time is up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently creating a fighting game, and I have two sprites (the player is blue and the enemy is red). I currently have a working timer. However, after the time is up, the sprites can still attack each other and the text in the middle will change constantly (it will make more sense if you run the snippet).

**Question:** How can I make it so that my sprites cannot attack each other after the timer is finished?

***Side*** question: How can I also stop my sprites from moving after the timer runs out? I feel like if the first on gets answered, I can do this question

Note: I am not using any libraries or frameworks, I am using native JavaScript, CSS, and HTML.

Note: Using "enter" or "space", make when of the sprites get down to no health. Then with the other sprite, smack that original one a bunch more. Eventually, the text will switch from "Player 1/2 wins!" to "Player 2/1 wins!", even though the health is already gone.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const winnerDisplay = document.querySelector('#winner-display');

canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 576;

function logMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + '. ';
}

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

const gravity = 0.7;

class Sprite {
    constructor({position, velocity, color, offset}) {
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.height = 150;
        this.width = 50;
        this.lastKey;
        this.attackBox = {
            position: {
                x: this.position.x,
                y: this.position.y
            },
            offset,
            width: 100,
            height: 50,
            color: 'green'
        }
        this.color = color;
        this.isAttacking;
        this.health = 100;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);

        //Attack box
        if (this.isAttacking) {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.attackBox.color;
            ctx.fillRect(
                this.attackBox.position.x,
                this.attackBox.position.y,
                this.attackBox.width,
                this.attackBox.height
            )
        }
    }

    update() {
        this.draw();
        this.attackBox.position.x = this.position.x - this.attackBox.offset.x;
        this.attackBox.position.y = this.position.y;
        this.position.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(canvas.width - this.width, this.position.x + this.velocity.x));
        this.position.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(canvas.height, this.position.y + this.velocity.y));

        if (this.position.y + this.height + this.velocity.y >= canvas.height) {
            this.velocity.y = 0;
        } else {
            this.velocity.y += gravity;
        }
    }

    attack() {
        this.isAttacking = true;
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.isAttacking = false
        }, 50)
    }
}

const Player = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    offset: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    color: 'blue'
})

const Enemy = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: canvas.width,
        y: 100
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    offset: {
        x: 50,
        y: 0
    },
    color: 'red'
})

const keys = {
    w: {
        pressed: false
    },
    a: {
        pressed: false
    },
    d: {
        pressed: false
    },
    ArrowUp: {
        pressed: false
    },
    ArrowLeft: {
        pressed: false
    },
    ArrowRight: {
        pressed: false
    }
}

function rectangularCollision({rectangle1, rectangle2}) {
    return (
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.x + rectangle1.attackBox.width >= rectangle2.position.x &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.x <= rectangle2.position.x + rectangle2.width &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.y + rectangle1.attackBox.height >= rectangle2.position.y &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.y <= rectangle2.position.y + rectangle2.height &&
        rectangle1.isAttacking
    )
}

function determineWinner({ Player, Enemy, timerId }) {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    winnerDisplay.style.display = 'flex';

    if (Player.health == Enemy.health) {
        winnerDisplay.innerHTML = 'Tie!';
    }

    if (Player.health > Enemy.health) {
        winnerDisplay.innerHTML = 'Player 1 wins!';
    }

    if (Player.health < Enemy.health) {
        winnerDisplay.innerHTML = 'Player 2 wins!';
    }
}

//Timer and end game
//Feel free to change these starting values as you need
const startingMinutes = 1;
const startingSeconds = 30;
let time = startingMinutes * 60 + startingSeconds;
let timerId;

function decreaseTimer() {
    const timeLeft = document.querySelector('#time-left');

    if (time > 0) {
        timerId = setTimeout(decreaseTimer, 1000);

        const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        let seconds = time % 60;

        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        timeLeft.innerHTML = `0${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        time--;
    }

    if (time == 0) {
        timeLeft.innerHTML = `00:00`;
        determineWinner({ Player, Enemy, timerId });

        Player.position.x = 0;
        Enemy.position.x = canvas.width;
    }    
}

decreaseTimer();

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    Player.update();
    Enemy.update();

    //Player movement
    Player.velocity.x = 0;

    if (keys.a.pressed == true && Player.lastKey == "a") {
        Player.velocity.x = -5;
    } else if (keys.d.pressed == true && Player.lastKey == "d") {
        Player.velocity.x = 5;
    }

    //Enemy movement
    Enemy.velocity.x = 0;

    if (keys.ArrowLeft.pressed == true && Enemy.lastKey == "ArrowLeft") {
        Enemy.velocity.x = -5;
    } else if (keys.ArrowRight.pressed == true && Enemy.lastKey == "ArrowRight") {
        Enemy.velocity.x = 5;
    }

    //Detect for the player hitting the enemy
    if (rectangularCollision({rectangle1: Player, rectangle2: Enemy})) {
        Player.isAttacking = false;
        Enemy.health -= 20;
        document.querySelector('#enemy-health').style.width = Enemy.health + '%';
    } 
    
    //Detect for the enemy hitting the player
    if (rectangularCollision({rectangle1: Enemy, rectangle2: Player})) {
        Enemy.isAttacking = false;
        Player.health -= 20;
        document.querySelector('#player-health').style.width = Player.health + '%';
    }  
    
    //End game based on health
    if (Enemy.health <= 0 || Player.health <= 0) {
        determineWinner({ Player, Enemy, timerId });
    }
}

animate();

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    switch (event.key) {
        //Player movement
        case 'w':
            Player.velocity.y = -20;
        break;

        case 'a':
            keys.a.pressed = true;
            Player.lastKey = "a";
        break

        case 'd':
            keys.d.pressed = true;
            Player.lastKey = "d";
        break;

        case ' ':
            Player.attack();
        break;    
    }

    //Enemy movement
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            Enemy.velocity.y = -20;
        break;

        case 'ArrowRight':
            keys.ArrowRight.pressed = true;
            Enemy.lastKey = 'ArrowRight'
        break

        case 'ArrowLeft':
            keys.ArrowLeft.pressed = true;
            Enemy.lastKey = 'ArrowLeft'
        break;

        case 'Enter':
            Enemy.attack();
        break;    
    }    
})

window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    //Player keys
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'w':
            keys.w.pressed = false;
        break;    

        case 'a':
            keys.a.pressed = false;
        break

        case 'd':
            keys.d.pressed = false;
        break;
    }

    //Enemy keys
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            keys.ArrowUp.pressed = false;
        break;    

        case 'ArrowLeft':
            keys.ArrowLeft.pressed = false;
        break

        case 'ArrowRight':
            keys.ArrowRight.pressed = false;
        break;
    }
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mother-div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#small-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.healthDiv {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.backgroundHealth {
    background-color: red;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%
}

#player-health {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lime;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%
}

#enemy-health {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0
}

#playerHealthDiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#timer {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border: solid white 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#winner-display {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Fighting Game</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Red container div-->
        <div id="mother-div">
            <!--Smaller red container div-->
            <div id="small-container">
                <!--Player Health-->
                <div class="healthDiv" id="playerHealthDiv">
                    <div class="backgroundHealth"></div>
                    <div id="player-health"></div>
                </div>

                <!--Timer-->
                <div id="timer">
                    <span id="time-left">02:00</span>
                </div>

                <!--Enemy Health-->
                <div class="healthDiv">
                    <div class="backgroundHealth"></div>
                    <div id="enemy-health"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Winner display-->
            <div id="winner-display"></div>

            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>

        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Track overall game state**

Use a variable to track the state of the game and help orchestrate the entire user experience.

How you track state(s) is up to you. It could be a single boolean variable (true/false) or an ENUM (e.g. 'loading', 'intro', 'paused', 'active', 'over', etc). In any case, you'd make something to hold the state of the game.

Going deeper, you'd probably also hold states for game rounds (e.g. current round, or number of rounds, etc), what the current character is (in the case where game characters can be swapped), whether a player has a boost mode enabled, etc.

In any case, during the game, you set-or-get state(s) during certain events:

1. Timer start
2. Timer end
3. Winner determined
4. Key press
5. Game paused
6. etc...

To illustrate, here I make a global var "gameIsActive":

```
var gameIsActive = true
```

Then, at certain events, we set state, for example, when the timer finishes:

```
gameIsActive = false
```

Then, at certain events, we get state and do logic accordingly, for example, movement only occurs when `gameIsActive` is `true`:

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (gameIsActive) {
        // do stuff...
```

**Here it is applied to your mini-game:**

https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/OJqLRWK?editors=1111

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const winnerDisplay = document.querySelector('#winner-display');

// NEW
var gameIsActive = true;

canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 576;

function logMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + '. ';
}

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

const gravity = 0.7;

class Sprite {
    constructor({position, velocity, color, offset}) {
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.height = 150;
        this.width = 50;
        this.lastKey;
        this.attackBox = {
            position: {
                x: this.position.x,
                y: this.position.y
            },
            offset,
            width: 100,
            height: 50,
            color: 'green'
        }
        this.color = color;
        this.isAttacking;
        this.health = 100;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);

        //Attack box
        if (this.isAttacking) {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.attackBox.color;
            ctx.fillRect(
                this.attackBox.position.x,
                this.attackBox.position.y,
                this.attackBox.width,
                this.attackBox.height
            )
        }
    }

    update() {
        this.draw();
        this.attackBox.position.x = this.position.x - this.attackBox.offset.x;
        this.attackBox.position.y = this.position.y;
        this.position.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(canvas.width - this.width, this.position.x + this.velocity.x));
        this.position.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(canvas.height, this.position.y + this.velocity.y));

        if (this.position.y + this.height + this.velocity.y >= canvas.height) {
            this.velocity.y = 0;
        } else {
            this.velocity.y += gravity;
        }
    }

    attack() {
        this.isAttacking = true;
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.isAttacking = false
        }, 50)
    }
}

const Player = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    offset: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    color: 'blue'
})

const Enemy = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: canvas.width,
        y: 100
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    offset: {
        x: 50,
        y: 0
    },
    color: 'red'
})

const keys = {
    w: {
        pressed: false
    },
    a: {
        pressed: false
    },
    d: {
        pressed: false
    },
    ArrowUp: {
        pressed: false
    },
    ArrowLeft: {
        pressed: false
    },
    ArrowRight: {
        pressed: false
    }
}

function rectangularCollision({rectangle1, rectangle2}) {
    return (
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.x + rectangle1.attackBox.width >= rectangle2.position.x &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.x <= rectangle2.position.x + rectangle2.width &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.y + rectangle1.attackBox.height >= rectangle2.position.y &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.y <= rectangle2.position.y + rectangle2.height &&
        rectangle1.isAttacking
    )
}

function determineWinner({ Player, Enemy, timerId }) {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    winnerDisplay.style.display = 'flex';

    if (Player.health == Enemy.health) {
        winnerDisplay.innerHTML = 'Tie!';
    }

    if (Player.health > Enemy.health) {
        winnerDisplay.innerHTML = 'Player 1 wins!';
    }

    if (Player.health < Enemy.health) {
        winnerDisplay.innerHTML = 'Player 2 wins!';
    }
}

//Timer and end game
//Feel free to change these starting values as you need
const startingMinutes = 1;
const startingSeconds = 30;
let time = startingMinutes * 60 + startingSeconds;
let timerId;

function decreaseTimer() {
    const timeLeft = document.querySelector('#time-left');

    if (time > 0) {
        timerId = setTimeout(decreaseTimer, 1000);

        const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        let seconds = time % 60;

        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        timeLeft.innerHTML = `0${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        time--;
    }

    if (time == 0) {
        timeLeft.innerHTML = `00:00`;

        // NEW
        gameIsActive = false;

        determineWinner({ Player, Enemy, timerId });

        Player.position.x = 0;
        Enemy.position.x = canvas.width;
    }    
}

decreaseTimer();

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    Player.update();
    Enemy.update();

    //Player movement
    Player.velocity.x = 0;

    if (keys.a.pressed == true && Player.lastKey == "a") {
        Player.velocity.x = -5;
    } else if (keys.d.pressed == true && Player.lastKey == "d") {
        Player.velocity.x = 5;
    }

    //Enemy movement
    Enemy.velocity.x = 0;

    if (keys.ArrowLeft.pressed == true && Enemy.lastKey == "ArrowLeft") {
        Enemy.velocity.x = -5;
    } else if (keys.ArrowRight.pressed == true && Enemy.lastKey == "ArrowRight") {
        Enemy.velocity.x = 5;
    }

    //Detect for the player hitting the enemy
    if (rectangularCollision({rectangle1: Player, rectangle2: Enemy})) {
        Player.isAttacking = false;
        Enemy.health -= 20;
        document.querySelector('#enemy-health').style.width = Enemy.health + '%';
    } 
    
    //Detect for the enemy hitting the player
    if (rectangularCollision({rectangle1: Enemy, rectangle2: Player})) {
        Enemy.isAttacking = false;
        Player.health -= 20;
        document.querySelector('#player-health').style.width = Player.health + '%';
    }  
    
    //End game based on health
    if (Enemy.health <= 0 || Player.health <= 0) {

        // NEW
        gameIsActive = false;

        determineWinner({ Player, Enemy, timerId });
    }
}

animate();

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  
  // NEW 
  if (gameIsActive) {
     
      switch (event.key) {
          //Player movement
          case 'w':
              Player.velocity.y = -20;
          break;

          case 'a':
              keys.a.pressed = true;
              Player.lastKey = "a";
          break

          case 'd':
              keys.d.pressed = true;
              Player.lastKey = "d";
          break;

          case ' ':
              Player.attack();
          break;    
      }

      //Enemy movement
      switch (event.key) {
          case 'ArrowUp':
              Enemy.velocity.y = -20;
          break;

          case 'ArrowRight':
              keys.ArrowRight.pressed = true;
              Enemy.lastKey = 'ArrowRight'
          break

          case 'ArrowLeft':
              keys.ArrowLeft.pressed = true;
              Enemy.lastKey = 'ArrowLeft'
          break;

          case 'Enter':
              Enemy.attack();
          break;    
      }    
   }
})

window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  
  // NEW 
  if (gameIsActive) {
    
    //Player keys
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'w':
            keys.w.pressed = false;
        break;    

        case 'a':
            keys.a.pressed = false;
        break

        case 'd':
            keys.d.pressed = false;
        break;
    }

    //Enemy keys
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            keys.ArrowUp.pressed = false;
        break;    

        case 'ArrowLeft':
            keys.ArrowLeft.pressed = false;
        break

        case 'ArrowRight':
            keys.ArrowRight.pressed = false;
        break;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mother-div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#small-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.healthDiv {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.backgroundHealth {
    background-color: red;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%
}

#player-health {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lime;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%
}

#enemy-health {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0
}

#playerHealthDiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#timer {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border: solid white 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#winner-display {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Fighting Game</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Red container div-->
        <div id="mother-div">
            <!--Smaller red container div-->
            <div id="small-container">
                <!--Player Health-->
                <div class="healthDiv" id="playerHealthDiv">
                    <div class="backgroundHealth"></div>
                    <div id="player-health"></div>
                </div>

                <!--Timer-->
                <div id="timer">
                    <span id="time-left">02:00</span>
                </div>

                <!--Enemy Health-->
                <div class="healthDiv">
                    <div class="backgroundHealth"></div>
                    <div id="enemy-health"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Winner display-->
            <div id="winner-display"></div>

            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>

        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```